# how to copy text from auto complete text box to edit box

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-widget

I was developing one notepad kind of thing in which user can enter in edit text, I have also provided one Auto complete text view which help him in writing quick word. but I am not getting how can I add the word from auto text box to edit box without disturbing previous written text.

**MY Try**: I tried this code

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
                String c = s.toString(); // read Content
                ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_text_area)).setText(c); 
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){ }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){ }
        });
```

which is coping the text in edit box but also deleting the previously written text. How can I add the word from AutoCompleteTextView to edit box without deleting anything and Also when user select any word, and word appear in edit box Auto text box should become empty.

Is there some API in android

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get your question. You have an Edit Text AND an AutocompleteText? And when the user types sth and it is shown by the AutocompleteText, then the user can pick that word and it should be shown in the EditText?

Comment: Yes, Its just helps the user not to type complete word and select from auto complete by typing few word. Like Tatterdemalion, user need not to type it complete, just tat may provide words which contain his required word. and can select from there. and as ho selects it , word appears in continuation of written text. hope u understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using OnItemClickListener on your AutoComplete. When the user clicks at a word you can save the position of it. Use that int value to retrieve your word from the specified position of your ArrayList, Adapter or whatever it is your are using as datasource for your AutoCompleteList.

Comment: As I am doing demo, i am using String array, but no success

Comment: means, method did not brought fruitful result

Comment: Ok your suggestion helped me, although I had to do few modification. But any ways, this is done. For those who may need, I am adding it as answer, but accepting urs as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `onFocusChange()`. May be that help..........

Answer (score 0):

Well as what Duzi suggested, this is my code:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete);
         final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_text_area);
         textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    editText.append(textView.getText().toString());
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                }
            });
```

Thanks everyone